# Django html format radio select labels

Tags: django

Consider the following structure:

`models.py`:

```py
class modela(models.Model):
    fielda = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=((True, 'some <b>bold</b> text'), (False, 'zzz')))
```

`forms.py`:

```py
class forma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = modela
        widgets = {'fielda': forms.RadioSelect}
        fields = '__all__'
```

`views.py`:

```py
def a(request):
    form = forma()
    return render(request, 'a.html', {'form': form})
```

`a.html`:

```
{{ form.fielda }}
```

Django kindly escapes the tags for me as

[image: Django render result]

How do I render it as HTML tags like

[image: Expected result]

`{{ form.fielda | safe }}` doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [django.utils.safestring.mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) method to mark the string as safe for outputting in your template

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class modela(models.Model):
    fielda = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=((True, mark_safe('some <b>bold</b> text')), (False, 'zzz')))
```

Comment: That's cool! But what's the difference between the `safe` filter?

Comment: By the time the filter is applied the label will have already been rendered, the rendering of form fields by Django is pretty messy to follow but just to generate the field tens of templates and render calls are most likely used